# python -v and python3 -V gives different version in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, versions

`python -V` gives output as:

```
python3.11.1
```

`python3 -V` gives output as:

```
python3.10.6.
```

What does this mean? Which version is my Ubuntu 22.04 using by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Python version for Ubuntu 22.04 is Python 3.10.6, and this is what the system uses by default.

```
$ stat /usr/bin/python3
  File: /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.10
  Size: 10              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 10302h/66306d   Inode: 10486495    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

The symlink `/usr/bin/python` does not normally exist, so this must have been created when you installed Python 3.11.

So any application calling `/usr/bin/python` will use Python 3.11.